# SQL Server 2012 : after this installation complete SQL feature installation window not open

Tags: sql-server, failed-installation

[image]

Please help after this complete SQL Server setup installation not open how can I install SQL

Comment: Was there any error or?

Answer (score 0):

The set setup program is downloding update package.
You can uncheck the download update option zt before step.